# I want to pass an angular component as a property value of an object

Tags: javascript, angular, string, components

I want to update the title property by adding icon component like that

title: `Following` +`<lh-icon  src="lh-app-spaces.svg"></lh-icon>` + name,

but it doesn't work and it appears as a plain string in the HTML like that:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is use innerHTML in your div, like this:

```html
<div [innerHTML]="someVariable">
</div>
```

In this variable, you'll put your HTML to be rendered

### Another approach

```html
{{someVariable1}} <lh-icon  [src]="someVariable2"></lh-icon> {{someVariable3}}
```

In this form, you just need to pass the src of the icon and the names of the title